# Deploying sentry on AWS using fargate

Tags: amazon-ecs, sentry

I am trying to deploy sentry on aws-fargate using terraform. I am also launching Redis cluster and Postgres DB in RDS. I can launch the stack but as this is a new database i need to upgrade using exec command.(example command)

```
docker-compose exec sentry sentry upgrade
```

and then restart the sentry service to proceed. How can I achieve this using fargate.